# POST REDIRECT GET in form that submits to itself duplicate entries in database

Tags: php, html, forms

I am having the hardest time of my life for not understanding the basics of the POST REDIRECT GET pattern in forms that submit to themselves.
The main problem is that when the user goes back or refreshes the page, I get duplicate entries in the database
So basically I have a page that contains two forms, each one submits to itself.
I have some code implemented regarding the PRG pattern but it doesn't seem to work.
I'll post a brief example where I'll try to explain what I am doing.

```
    <?php
    function saveUser1($UserName_1)
    {
    include 'db_conn.php';
    //MySQL code etc...    
        if($result) return 1; //registro correcto
        else return -2; //error
        header('Location: samepage.php' , true, 303);
    exit();
    }

    function saveUser2($UserName_2)
    {
    include 'db_conn.php';
    //MySQL code etc...    
        if($result) return 1; //registro correcto
        else return -2; //error
        header('Location: samepage.php' , true, 303);
    exit();
    }

    $error1 = 0;
    $error2 = 0;

    if(isset($_POST['userForm1']))
    {
        $error1 = saveUser1(clean_form($_POST['txtUserName_1']);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['userForm2']))
    {
        $error2 = saveUser2(clean_form($_POST['txtUserName_2']);
    }
    ?>
```

Now the HTML

```
    <form action="" name="userForm1" method="POST">
    <label for="data">Some Data</label>
    <input type="text" value="some test data to post" name="txtUserName_1" id="txtUserName_1" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="userForm1" id="userForm1"/>
    </form>

    <form action="" name="userForm2" method="POST">
    <label for="data">Some Data</label>
    <input type="text" value="some test data to post" name="txtUserName_2" id="txtUserName_2" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="userForm2" id="userForm2"/>
    </form>
```

I just created this code in example of what I am trying to accomplish, but I haven't had any luck with the PGR pattern.
Could you guys tell me where the error is? Or redirect me (no kidding) to some good tutorial regarding this subject?
I have been looking to a lot of questions / answers, blogs but I can't find anything really solid (from my point of view).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I kind of solved, if anyone looking for the same anwser, you need to create a second php page where you will be inserting the data into the database, then, after that, you will redirect the user to the initial page where the form is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is sample code if you want try.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name">
    Email: <input type="text" name="email">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="send">
</form>
```

**PHP Code and common.php is database connection file**

```
<?php
   require_once "common.php";

   if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
   {
      $name = $_POST['name'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      $check = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE name = '".$name."' AND email = '".$email."' AND password = '".$password."'";
      $check_result = mysql_query($check) or die(mysql_error());

      if(mysql_num_rows($check_result) > 0)
      {
        header('Location : post.php');
      }
      else
      { 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (name,email,password) VALUES ('$name','$email','$password')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      } 
   }    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for the form name itself check for a unique field within the form. E.g. If(isset($_POST[txtUserName_1'']))

The form name itself won't exist in the post.

To see what gets posted try:

print_r($_POST);
exit;

Comment: How is that going to prevent re posting of the submitted information into the database?

Comment: It'll be unique to the one form submission. I'm not sure why you have two forms / methods etc but that'll make the structure you have work

Comment: But reloading the page will cause the resubmission the that unique field if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: You're calling saveUser1() within each isset() check, is that correct?

Comment: My mistake, each function is for each form, let me correct the code.

Comment: The forms and fuctions works as I want them to work, but when going back or refreshing, I get duplicates entries on the database, this is just to exemplify what I am trying to achive, I have about 8 forms and 8 functions in one single page.

Comment: When going back or refreshing you will be executing the code again so there will be duplicates. There's nothing in your code to deal with duplicates and noting in your original question relating to duplicates!

Comment: The POST REDIRECT GET method is used to eliminate the resubmitting of forms. anyway I'll add your comment to the question sp I can make more clear, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to set the post action to the same page.
And your form should not have the same name as your submit buttons(not sure about that).

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >    
<label for="data">Some Data</label>
<input type="text" value="some test data to post" name="data" id="data" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="userForm1"/>
</form>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" name="form2" method="POST">
<label for="data">Some Data</label>
<input type="text" value="some test data to post" name="data" id="data" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" id="userForm2"/>
</form>
```

For the php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $error1 = saveUser1(clean_form($_POST['txtUserName_1']);
}
if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
    $error1 = saveUser1(clean_form($_POST['txtUserName_2']);
}
```

you can add a hidden field for checking if its executed:

```
<input type="hidden" name="executed" value="0"/>
```

then you can set it to 0 when you have executed the mysql query

```
function saveUser1($UserName_1)
{
if($_POST['executed'] == 0)
{
include 'db_conn.php';
//MySQL code etc...    
    if($result) $_POST['executed'] = 1; //registro correcto
    header('Location: samepage.php' , true, 303);
exit();
}
}
```

Comment: Just tried it and it didn't work, reloaded and got a duplicate entry.